# Open 2 windows in 1 window

Tags: fedora, gnome, remote-desktop

When doing a presentation, I only have the option of sharing a window or sharing the entire screen. I don't want to share the whole screen because I want to see the speaker's notes on my screen. However, in my presentation, I want to switch between the display (Google slides in Chrome and the terminal).

What is the easiest way I can open these 2 in 1 window? Possible solutions:

- Open the terminal in Chrome by SSHing to localhost using something like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell-extension/iodihamcpbpeioajjeobimgagajmlibd
- Open window manager in a new window (Is this possible? I'm using Gnome 3.28.2)
- Using something like Team Viewer or Chrome Remote Desktop against localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Install wayland. There's a compositor named 'weston' that comes with it. You can run it as an X client and run whatever programs (chrome and terminal) inside it and share it.

Comment: This seems appealing.  Would you elaborate or provide some links that provide some details and examples?